# Software testing with version control

Tags: testing, version-control

So, as a developer, you probably write a small amount of code, and then test it to see if it works before you move onto something else. This is because you don't want to write thousands of lines of code and find that doesn't work. Stating the obvious here. So myself and a few others(soon) are working on a php application where I want to implement some form of version control, most likely subversion since we all know how to use it, somewhat. My question is how do I implement this writing process stated above with writing, and then testing.

My idea was to set each developer up with their own workstation including a web server, and php/mysql etc.. so they can checkout the repo and then test on their own computer as they are writing. I'm really looking for some direction here with that. Currently we aren't using version control as there are only two developers and we simply use a shared directory thats located on the web server. When we make changes, we can view them immediately on the web server. Any input on this? Whats the best way to handle multiple developers when in the development process of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to approach this:

1) Each developer has a whole web server stack on their machine, deploys to it, and tests there, then checks in working code.

2) There's a separate test/integration machine. Developers take turns deploying to that machine, do their testing, then check in working code.

3) You use branches in Subversion. Development happens on a branch, and it's OK to check in broken code on a branch. There may be a branch for each developer, or a branch for each feature, or whatever. The developer checks in code onto the branch, checks it out on the separate test machine, tests, fixes, then checks the working code onto the trunk.

Which one is right depends on how big your team is and how complex your server setup is. Choose one that makes sense for your team.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted to hear. Now I feel as if option one is probably better for our team, and its what I suggested in the question post. Option two would involve me getting use to deploying code to a test machine after every change I've made. The only issue I have with each developer having their own stack is the database we are using to test with. Making a copy of this at this point in time, when the database isn't completely done would, probably be a pain because there are changes being made every so often to the structure. Although, we could just setup a remote database.

Comment: @user766554's answer about a continuous integration server is good, too, and I would take that seriously; in my experience most teams prefer to be able to test stuff before checking in, though; it's awkward to check in and then wait for a failure email to go to your whole team. If you have to iterate a few times like that, it's not very pleasant. So I'd recommend it *in addition to* my suggestions, rather than *in place of.*

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to start thinking about a build server, using a piece of software like cruisecontrol which monitors for source code changes and is then able to build, run tests and deploy you're code (ed: in a manner as close to live like as possible!).

I'd highly recommend integrating a build server as soon as possible, otherwise you'll find out down the line that automating something that somebody has been doing manually for the last 5 years is somewhat difficult :)

You might also find that each dev ends up with their own methods of deployment and custom environment, it'd be far better to centralise this in one place and then have other devs use the scripts and from that deployment if they want to run the same process locally.

Configuration management is something you want to get right to begin with!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to CruiseControl.

Comment: I believe other options are TeamCity and Hudson.  We use "Go" in our workplace but it's not free and feels rather immature.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing with CI: You only want to push working code to the central repository.  This requires a private repository for each developer, but has the advantage that you never break trunk.
Git and Mercurial are the most obvious tools, and can work with svn as a central repository.

To prevent merge conflicts, there's one trick to prevent pushing broken code to central: always pull/merge from central first, and frequently, prior to pushing:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html

And have a look at our sponsor: http://hginit.com for examples of workflows with multiple developers.